# Envio de Array PHP POST AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, array

Compañeros, saludos a todos.
Tengo la siguiente inquietud. Necesito enviar una serie de variables por POST en una funcion ajax.
La idea de esto, es que una vez ejecutada las inserciones en la base de datos, me envie a otro archivo que se encarga de imprimir un comprobante de venta.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
$inserta = "INSERT INTO pago_parcial (folio_venta,id_venta,id_cl,mesa,nom_mesa,ubicacion,piso,id_cierre,neto,propina,total,fecha_pago)
  VALUES('$folio','$array_implode','$id_cl','$mesa','$nom_mesa','$id_ub','$piso','$id_caja','$neto','$propina','$total','$fecha_pago')";

$result=mysql_query($inserta);
if(mysql_errno()!=0){
    echo "Ingresando Error: ".mysql_error();
}else{

  echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function enviar() {
        var idventa = '.$folio.';
        var idmesa = '.$mesa.';
        var ubicacion = '.$id_ub.';
        var id_de_la_mesa = '.$id_de_la_mesa.';
        var piso = '.$piso.';
        var ids = '.$ids.';// aqui tengo el problema
        $.ajax({
          url: "ticket_pago_individual.php",
          type: "post",
          data: {"idventa" : idventa, "mesa" : idmesa, "idub" : ubicacion, "id_de_la_mesa" : id_de_la_mesa, "piso" : piso, "ids" : ids},
        });
      }
      enviar();

            </SCRIPT>';
}
```

Todas las variables se envian correctamente a excepcion de ids, ya que es un array previamente creado en PHP y que viene con datos desde la BD.
Como ejemplo, pongo el siguiente array:

```
$ids = array(1, 2);
```

Alguna sugerencia de como enviar ese array por ajax, recuperarlo en el archivo de destino y poder procesar la solicitud?

Agradecido como siempre por su ayuda u orientacion.

Comment: No puedes concatenar un array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues supongo, que lo que necesitas es convertir ese array de php a un array que pueda entender JavaScript, así que para ello, tendrás que usar la función json_encodey, te pondré unos ejemplos y la página de la documentación más abajo..

```
<?php
    $a = array('<foo>',"'bar'",'"baz"','&blong&');

    echo "Normal: ",  json_encode($a), "\n";
    echo "Tags: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG), "\n";
    echo "Apos: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_APOS), "\n";
    echo "Quot: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_QUOT), "\n";
    echo "Amp: ",     json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_AMP), "\n";
    echo "Unicode: ", json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n";
    echo "All: ",     json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "\n\n";
?>
```

El resultado de la ejecución de más arriba es:

```
Normal: ["","'bar'","\"baz\"","&blong&"]
Tags: ["\u003Cfoo\u003E","'bar'","\"baz\"","&blong&"]
Apos: ["","\u0027bar\u0027","\"baz\"","&blong&"]
Quot: ["","'bar'","\u0022baz\u0022","&blong&"]
Amp: ["","'bar'","\"baz\"","\u0026blong\u0026"]
Unicode: ["","'bar'","\"baz\"","&blong&"]
All: ["\u003Cfoo\u003E","\u0027bar\u0027","\u0022baz\u0022","\u0026blong\u0026"]
```

Y la página de la documentación es: [function.json-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

La solución a tu problema, podría ser esta:

```
echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function enviar() {
    var idventa = '.$folio.';
    var idmesa = '.$mesa.';
    var ubicacion = '.$id_ub.';
    var id_de_la_mesa = '.$id_de_la_mesa.';
    var piso = '.$piso.';
    var ids = '.json_encode($ids).';// aquí está la solución
    $.ajax({
      url: "ticket_pago_individual.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {"idventa" : idventa, "mesa" : idmesa, "idub" : ubicacion, "id_de_la_mesa" : id_de_la_mesa, "piso" : piso, "ids" : ids},
    });
  }
  enviar();

        </SCRIPT>';
```

Espero que te ayude.

Un saludo!

Comment: estimado, muchisimas gracias por orientarme. agredezco tu tiempo y me demore en responder porque lei la documentacion que enviaste y me ayudo en el problema que tenia.

Comment: Me alegra muchísimo saber que te ha sido de utilidad :)

Comment: Si estimado. no habia tenido la oportunidad de lidiar con un problema asi antes, pero con la documentacion mas tu ejemplo que me diste, tengo los conceptos muchos mas claro. Saludos y gracias nuevamente